# How to Get Date only or Time only output in react-native

Tags: android, datetime, react-native

I am developing an app in react-native.
I am using an npm package called react-native-modal-datetime-picker for collecting date. But the output i am getting is mixture of date and time
            'Fri Feb 17 2017 16:06:00 GMT+0530 (IST)'
How cant collect only date in the format  format="DD-MM-YY" from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have it as an Javascript Date object you could do this:

```
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth();
var year = date.getFullYear();
```

After that you can format it how you like. Just remember that getMonth() is from (0-11), so you can add one to the result to get it like a "normal" calendar.

```
var string = day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
```

Answer (score 4):

I have faced same issues `javascript` should rename it to `DateTime` instead of just `Date`.

I would recommend you to use `moment.js` it will help you in timezones.

```
moment(new Date()).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
```

[read more](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Answer (score 1):

```
onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    var months = [
      'Jan',
      'Feb',
      'Mar',
      'Apr',
      'May',
      'Jun',
      'Jul',
      'Aug',
      'Sep',
      'Oct',
      'Nov',
      'Dec',
    ];

    const currentDate = selectedDate || this.state.date;
    this.setState({show: Platform.OS === 'ios'});
    this.setState((this.state.date = currentDate));

    // console.log('Month', currentDate.getMonth());
    console.log('Date', currentDate.getDate());

    var monthName = months[currentDate.getMonth()];
    console.log(monthName);
    // const Date = currentDate.toLocaleString('default', {month: 'long'});
    // console.log('Date:', Date);
    //Set Date
    this.setState({currDate: currentDate.getDate()});
    this.setState({currMonth: monthName});
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

For get a date few days forward from today {React TypeScript}: (It's also quite similar for previous date from today)

```
//This function is for calculating estimated Delivery Date
 let date = new Date();
  const estimatedDeliveryDate = (date: Date, day: number) => {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + day);
  };
  estimatedDeliveryDate(date, 3);
  var estimatedDate =
    date.getDate() + "-" + date.getMonth() + "-" + date.getFullYear();

console.log("Delivery Date: ", estimatedDate);
```